# join columns of arrays in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have the following inputs

- dataset 1 with tens of thousands of rows and 5 array columns
- dataset 2 with tens of thousands of rows and 3 array columns

I want to join/merge (add) the 3th column of dataset 1 to a new 4th array column of dataset 2 for the elements for which the ID is the same (same value in column 1 of dataset 1 and column 1 of dataset 2). Mathematically you can write it like this I think:

```
dataset2(i,4)=dataset1(find(dataset1(:,1)==c(i,1)),3);
```

but how to put it in MATLAB?

None of the methods mentioned in the MATLAB help function or elsewhere on the internet seem to work. I have already tried `merge`, `join`, `ismember`, `vectors`, but I can't solve the problem.

Does someone have any ideas? I know the problem can be solved with `for` loops, but i'm not allowed to use them, so I am searching for alternatives.

Comment: or is it really not possible in matlab to merge different columns of different arrays of different sizes based on overlapping ID?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want

```erlang
%We keep the index of all the matching rows
%NOTICE: I changed c(i,1) to dataset2(:,1)
%matches_in_col_1 = find(dataset1(:,1)==dataset2(:,1)); 

%EDIT: HOW TO COMPARE MORE THAN 2 COLUMNS
%if you want to find matches in 4 datasets just use this
matches_in_col_1 = find(dataset1(:,1)==dataset2(:,1)==dataset3(:,1)==dataset4(:,1)); 

%now copy the values from those rows into the corresponding row
%of datsaset2 
dataset2(matches_in_col_1,4) = dataset1(matches_in_col_1,3);
```

I'm not 100% sure. Why is `i` present? were you trying a loop implementation? My solution also assumes that `c` was supposed to be `dataset2`

Comment: yes, c is indeed dataset 2. But with this method, how do you define out of which arrays you take column 1, i have also other files (dataset 3,4, ...) in the script but they don't need change.  So, what i want is to put for the elements for which is the ID is the same (for elements for which column 1 for both dataset is equal), to put the elements of the 3th column of dataset 1 to a new made column of dataset2 ; and the matrices are not the same, by the method you propose i get the error 'matrix dimensions must agree' and that is not the case.

Comment: or is that just impossible in matlab?

Comment: @WouterJohns I made an edit to the code for matching 4 datasets. you just extend the compare expression. All the datasets **must** have the same number of rows, but they can have different numbers of columns.  When you say `datasetX(:,1)` you are saying all rows, and to do the comparison all the datasets must have the same number of rows